Movie I saw in the 80s where a substance oozed off of movie stairs leaving a wet cat behind
I remember this movie as a summer movie in the early 80s. My movie experts have watched even the worst blob movies to rule that out.
All I remember is where a substance is oozing back out of a movie theater (maybe) and the stairs are red carpet. As the ooze is leaving, it uncovers a wet cat.

I love that you have a stable of movie experts to heroically watch the blob films for you! :)

One is my husband and the other it's his his best friend. They are amazing!!!

I believe that you are remembering a scene from "Godzilla vs Hedorah" (titled "Godzilla vs the Smog Monster" in the USA) from 1972. The cat appears at the end of a scene where the pollution monster Hedorah fills a nightclub with its vile substance, killing all of the club-goers, but somehow sparing the cat.

Hedorah first appears as a tadpole-shaped sea monster, then comes ashore on four legs, evolves to a bipedal stance, and then morphs into a manta ray-like form which flies on jets of sulfuric acid, reducing the people on the street to bones. Hedorah feeds from factory chimneys, and exudes gray muck as a weapon - in the final battle he nearly drowns Godzilla in the stuff.

This is it!! Thank you so much!!

@KateyKelly-Collins You should click the checkmark to the upper left of this answer in order order to "accept" it as answering your question.

Fun trivia: the monster Hedorah's name comes from the Japanese word hedo meaning "vomit" + the same ra on the end of Gojira (the Japanese original version of what became "Godzilla" in the English-speaking world).

Ah, yes, survivors: the camera person and the cat, though the cat may need to surrender one of nine life cards. (Ya, so sometimes luck is around loose for a few other folks.)
